# Pydantic 1.9.1: is there a way to avoid the "if field in values" pattern?

Tags: python, pydantic

Let's compare two Model objects and the following dictionary.

```
class A(BaseModel):
    field1: StrictStr
    field2: StrictStr

    @validator('field2', always=True)
    def check_field2_not_dupliated(cls, field2, values):
        if field2 == values['field1'] + 'x':
            raise ValueError(f'{field2=} is the same as field1!')
        return field2

class B(BaseModel):
    field1: StrictStr
    field2: StrictStr

    @validator('field2', always=True)
    def check_field2_not_dupliated(cls, field2, values):
        if 'field1' in values:
            if field2 == values['field1'] + 'x':
                raise ValueError(f'{field2=} is the same as field1!')
        return field2

d = {
    'field1': 1,
    'field2': 'hello'
}
```

If you run `parse_obj`, you get

```
> A.parse_obj(d)

      5 @validator('field2', always=True)
      6 def check_field2_not_dupliated(cls, field2, values):
----> 7     if field2 == values['field1']:
      8         raise ValueError(f'{field2=} is the same as field1!')
      9     return field2

KeyError: 'field1'
```

```
> B.parse_obj(d)
ValidationError: 1 validation error for B
field1
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)
```

**I would like the error message of B without needing to have to wrap the validator for field2 in "if 'field1' in values", that is, with code looking like A**.

One possible approach I'm not sure whether is possible is throwing an error once pydantic realizes `field1` has invalid input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Comment: Edited my question. There are more complicated instances where essentially I expect either `field1` to be a valid string or an error to already have been thrown

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.get` to safely read a value from a dict, so in this case

```
if field2 == values.get('field1', None):  # or whatever default value if not found
```